# System.web.mvc and System.web.routing.. Do they have to be kept with versions in synch? ie 4.0=4.0

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

One of the guys here at work was saying that System.Web.MVC.dll version number (3.0, 40, etc) has to match the version of System.Web.Routing.dll...

I wanted to understand his statement, so I dug into it and can't find anything on the web by googling.

I looked on my hard drive and if they need to be in synch I'd expect them to be in the same package. They are not. Routing is in the framework and MVC is in it's own custom location from it's installer.

So the question is, do they have to be in synch? Our references specify MVC version 3.0.0.0 but routing is not specified, it's the one that matches the version of .NET we are using (in this case 4.5)

Is that Kosher? If not can you please explain why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System.web.routing is actually an empty assembly.  All of the actual functions are in System.Web.MVC

This was probably done so that Webforms apps would not need to include a reference to system.web.mvc.

If you notice, System.Web.Routing is only 22k, at least in .net 4.5.1.

Assemblies have version dependencies.. so they often won't work with other assemblies of different versions, you have to check on an assembly by assembly basis...

Comment: Run time tests? Ie if it compiles and runs that's good enough, or do I need to dig in with reflector and do it manually?

Comment: @EricBrown-Cal Well, the assembly will fail to bind if the dependency is version specific...